# Is it possible to run individual test cases/test classes on the command line with xcode 5?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode5

I can run all unit tests using the following command:

```
xcodebuild test -workspace Project.xcworkspace -scheme Scheme -sdk iphonesimulator7.0 -destination platform='iOS Simulator',OS=7.0,name='iPhone Retina (4-inch)'
```

Is there anything I can pass to this to run individual unit tests/classes in the same way that you can using the Xcode UI?

Cheers.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/37971495/580412

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not that I know of, and it's not on the man page either. But you have such option in the excellent [xctool](https://github.com/facebook/xctool) (`-only SomeTestTarget:SomeTestClass/testSomeMethod`).

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation - unfortunately it appears that xctool doesn't work with XCTests yet.

Comment: The fix is in a pull request if you are adventurous: https://github.com/facebook/xctool/issues/198 (didn't try it myself).

Comment: I think my problem is that they've broken Kiwi support now (as I couldn't even get it working using that pull request.) I think your answer is correct however and this is the best option.

Answer (score 4):

For those who are using later versions of Xcode (8.0+) and may run across this post in the future (like myself), this is now possible using the `-only-testing` flag, which is documented in the man page for `xcodebuild`. The format for using the flag is as follows:

```
xcodebuild \
    -destination "$DEST" \
    -workspace "$WRKSP" \
    -scheme "$SCHEME" \
    -only-testing:Target/Class/Method test
```

You can also omit elements from the path after the `-only-testing` flag, e.g. `-only-testing:Scheme/Class` will run all these tests within that class.

Here is a related Stackoverflow question, touching on the new functionality:
[How to use xcodebuild with -only-testing and -skip-testing flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427263/how-to-use-xcodebuild-with-only-testing-and-skip-testing-flag)

Comment: Yep, that's good point, but this was among the first results in multiple searches I made trying to find a solution to this problem. I'll update the answer to clarify!

Comment: For anyone who has issues with this, the `-only-testing` argument takes in `Target/Class/Method` NOT `Scheme/Class/Method`.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to edit the schemer of your test file and disable/enable the tests as you please. Then you can rerun the same command through the CLI and it will only run the tests you specified above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kiwi, you should supposedly be able to do it using the `KW_SPEC` environment variable. I haven't been able to, though: [Running a single KIWI spec with xctool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30387123/running-a-single-kiwi-spec-with-xctool).