# How to use xcodebuild with -only-testing and -skip-testing flag?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild

I've noticed that there are two options in `xcodebuild`'s man page.

```
-only-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER
```

> constrains testing by specifying tests to include, and excluding other tests

```
-skip-testing:TEST-IDENTIFIER
```

> constrains testing by specifying tests to exclude, but including other tests

What I try:

```
xcodebuild -workspace MyWorkSpace.xcworkspace / 
-sdk iphonesimulator / 
-destination id=7F52F302-C6AF-4215-B269-39A6F9913D5B / 
-scheme SCHEME-iOS / 
test -only-testing:???
```

What is `TEST-IDENTIFIER` mean ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Like what Marcio said, it's a path like string.

For example, say you have a scheme named MyScheme, a test target `MyUITests`, and testing class `LoginTest`, then testing method `testUserLogin`, to run only the method, you can run

```
xcodebuild -workspace Envoy.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyScheme \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air 2,OS=10.1'
    '-only-testing:MyUITests/LoginTest/testUserLogin' test
```

Likewise, if you want to run all tests under LoginTest, here you run

```
xcodebuild -workspace Envoy.xcworkspace \
    -scheme MyScheme \
    -sdk iphonesimulator \
    -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPad Air 2,OS=10.1'
    '-only-testing:MyUITests/LoginTest' test
```

Comment: is it some way to use regular expression for this parameter. Something like -only-testing:MyUItests/LoginTest[1-2]???

Comment: I just updated this answer, it was partially wrong and led me to waste about 30 minutes. In the `-only-testing` argument you specify the target not the scheme.

Comment: Updated the answer. Instead of `'-only-testing:MyUITests/LoginTest/testUserLogin()'`, it suppose to be `'-only-testing:MyUITests/LoginTest/testUserLogin` w/o `()` for the test case.

Answer (score 14):

You can check the video https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/409/

I used it like this:

-only-testing:UITests/TC_TextArea/test1

for my tests [tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziG9h.png). Works fine

Full command looks as follows:

```
command = 'xcodebuild test 
-workspace ' + pathToProjectWorkspaceFolder + '/project.xcworkspace 
-scheme yourApp.app 
-destination "platform=iOS,name=' + deviceName + '" 
-only-testing:UITests/TC_TextArea/test1'
```

Comment: TEST-IDENTIFIER is how Xcode maps your tests. Check your testing tree--the 5th tab on your left. In order to work you always have to start from the root, i.e, `xcodebuild test skip-testing:MyTestsBundleName/MyClassName/MyTestCaseName`

Answer (score 6):

In case you need to include several tests:

```
xcodebuild -project Some.xcodeproj \
-scheme AllTests -only-testing:PersistenceTests -only-testing:FoundationTests test
```

Documentation:

> An xcodebuild command can combine multiple constraint options, but
>   -only-testing: has precedence over -skip-testing:.

Comment: Having trouble finding a reference to this, can you source this? Cheers!

Comment: `man xcodebuild` :)

Answer (score 2):

```
xcodebuild \
 -workspace MyApp.xcworkspace \
 -scheme Automation \
 -destination 'platform=ios,name=My Real iPhone' \
 -only-testing:MyTestDirectory/TestClass/testMethodName \
 test-without-building
```

- No need for single quotation marks around only-testing
- No need for the sub-directory names as they are ignored e.g. MyTestDirectory/E2E/

Answer (score 1):

To test an application you need to go with the two steps:

> 1. build the application

```
    xcodebuild build-for-testing \
        -workspace "<your_xcworkspace>" \
        -scheme "<your_scheme>" \
        -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=<your_simulator>,OS=<simdevice_os_version>" \
        -derivedDataPath "All"
```

> 2. test it without building

```
    xcodebuild test-without-building \
        -xctestrun "All/Build/Products/<your_scheme>_iphonesimulator<simdevice_os_version>-x86_64.xctestrun" \
        -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=<your_simulator>,OS=<simdevice_os_version>" '-only-testing:<your_test_bundle_to_run>'  \
        -derivedDataPath 'build/reports/<your_test_bundle_to_run>'
```

Here, `<your_test_bundle_to_run>` indicates the `TEST-IDENTIFIER` that means 
How many categories or how many test cases under a category you want to run, that should be included under a test bundle[`<your_test_bundle_to_run>`]