# How to disable some test case in Test suit XCUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcuitest, uitest

Currently I have issue that I can't disable some test case ( XCUI Test ).

I already try to disable case from schema, It worked when I test from xcode but when I run it from script it doesn't work.

My Script

```
/usr/bin/xcodebuild test-without-building -derivedDataPath "build" -workspace tako_ios_superapp.xcworkspace -scheme PlatformUITest -configuration Debug -UseModernBuildSystem=NO -destination "platform=iOS Simulator,name=Platform_Regression,OS=13.3" -resultBundlePath Platform '-only-testing:(my_app_target)/MY_Test_suit'
```

After I run this script, It still run every test case in test suit. Have someone ever disable or skip test case by script ?
ps. The reason That I have to use command because I've to work with CI, It need script.

[My Schema that I disable test case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRtNl.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running from the command line, the Xcode run/skip schema configuration is not used. You need to explicitly list what to test and what to skip.

See [How to use xcodebuild with -only-testing and -skip-testing flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39427263/how-to-use-xcodebuild-with-only-testing-and-skip-testing-flag) for more detail and discussion.

Comment: Thank you so much, Is it only one way to do right ? ( I mean it have to fix on CI config only )

Comment: Yes, that's the only way.